# Does TidyModels provide the capability to perform Many Models modeling?

Tags: tidymodels

I been using the TidyModels recently and was wondering if it has functionality for Many Models, similar to what was available in Modelr as presented in the Many Models chapter of R For Data Science.

I've looked through the documentation but have not seen this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tidymodels framework has more robust and expressive support for the kinds of tasks that modelr allows you to do, such as creating data resamples, piping models, etc. The [broom](/questions/tagged/broom) package is [part of tidymodels](https://broom.tidymodels.org/) with verbs like `tidy()` and `glance()` important parts of the tidymodels approach to modeling, and the [rsample](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/) package provides tools for resampling.

You may be interested in [checking out how to use this kind of approach for bootstrap estimates of model parameters](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/bootstrap/):

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.0 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.5.6          ✓ recipes   0.1.12    
#> ✓ dials     0.0.7          ✓ rsample   0.0.7     
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0          ✓ tibble    3.0.1     
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.1          ✓ tune      0.1.0     
#> ✓ infer     0.5.2          ✓ workflows 0.1.1.9000
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.1.9000     ✓ yardstick 0.0.6.9000
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
boots <- bootstraps(mtcars, times = 1000, apparent = TRUE)

fit_spline <- function(split) {
  data <- analysis(split)
  smooth.spline(data$wt, data$mpg, df = 4)
}

boot_models <- boots %>% 
  mutate(spline = map(splits, fit_spline))

boot_models %>% 
  sample_n(200) %>% 
  mutate(aug = map(spline, augment)) %>% 
  unnest(aug) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted, group = id), alpha = .2, col = "darkcyan") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

If you're interested in creating grids of model parameters, check out the [dials](https://dials.tidymodels.org/) package.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm a big fan of tidy models, but I'm still not clear if it supports many models. I'm just looking to reproduce the Many Models Chapter R4DS.  Again, thanks for the response and for the great Youtube videos that you produce - I've watched them all.

Comment: If you're looking at the gapminder example, most of that already uses broom/tidy/tidymodels but modelr still has functions like `add_residuals()`. If you are going to do resampling of a dataset, I think rsample is easier to use than modelr.